# nook tablet sdk and android sdk

Tags: android, nook-tablet

I was taking a look at the nook developer site on [barnesandnoble.com](https://nookdeveloper.barnesandnoble.com/tools-services/nook-tablet-sdk.html) and noticed that their claim is:

> The NOOK Tablet SDK contains the following components:
>
> Android Virtual Device (AVD) Emulator
>
> Android Debug Bridge (ADB)
>   configuration settings

I was wondering if that means that everything else is exactly the same as the android sdk except the emulator plugin and the adb settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - it is similar to the LG, Sony, Motorola SDK add-ons that are loaded as part of the official Android SDK.

The current links are below (but note that these seem to change quite often and are correct as of Jan 2012 - register and check with NOOK regularly).

[NOOK Tablet, API 10] http://su.barnesandnoble.com/nook/sdk/Nook_Tablet_addon.xml

[NOOK Color, API 8] http://su.barnesandnoble.com/nook/sdk/addon.xml

Once installed via android sdk manager (use Tools >> Manage Add-on Sites ), it should automagically update ADB drivers on Linux/Mac Osx and have emulators available via AVD.

You can run "android update adb" in order to get ADB functioning. I havent tested in Windows but this should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the emulator or the device itself?  The emulator is an approximation of the real hardware, but I don't think it includes all of the real software and configuration.

The emulator operates closely to a normal AVD, but with a different skin and different setup for Nook-specifics (e.g. /media is available to write).  However, some operations will appear to work in the emulator but cause a failure on a real device (or at least the QA testing).  Some of the Nook-specific workarounds won't work on the emulator (e.g. calling the Nook intent for wallpaper manager or the Nook store).